# Cannot mock simple object array with JustMock

Tags: c#, arrays, unit-testing, autofac, justmock

I'm using JustMock and AutoFac and trying to mock an array of a quite simple objects but I just can't seem to get the syntax right...

```
        var labResults = Mock.Create<LabResult[]>();

        Mock.Arrange(() => labResults).Returns(new LabResult[]
                                       {
                                           new LabResult
                                           {
                                               EstablishmentID = "0101",
                                               PatientID = "A11111111",
                                               EpisodeNo = 1,
                                               LabNumber = "975310A",
                                               Status = LabResultStatus.Initial,
                                               TestCode = "ABCD",
                                               DateUpdated = DateTime.Now
                                           },

                                           < snip >

                                           new LabResult
                                           {
                                               EstablishmentID = "0101",
                                               PatientID = "A11111112",
                                               EpisodeNo = 1,
                                               LabNumber = "975310A",
                                               Status = LabResultStatus.Final,
                                               TestCode = "ABC",
                                               DateUpdated = DateTime.Now
                                           },
                                   });
```

The code compiles fine but when run gives me a 'System.ArgumentException' error on the Mock.Create call - 'Additional information: Value was invalid'.

This one's had me stumped all morning and I cannot find a suitable example anywhere.  Can someone please tell me the correct syntax - it needs to be an array that comes back, not a List.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need mock. You are mocking an array, which can be just as well created *by-hand* simply by assigning values you already got in `Returns` part of mock setup. Like so:

```
var labResults = new LabResult[]
{ 
    new LabResult { ... },
    new LabResult { ... },
};
```

Comment: This, so much this. When I started using mocks in my tests I ended up trying to mock everything and everyone. In general I only mock/stub stuff when it's an expensive resource (i.e. when it uses network, IO, DB,...) or when I just want to check whether the collaboration between components is correct (i.e. does my system under test send out the correct messages to its collaborator?). Mocking collections or cheap and easy-to-construct input arguments only leads to more (and questionably unnecessary) work.

Comment: Especially in a language like C# where you need interfaces or the virtual keyword everywhere for a mocking framework to work effectively on such a low level.

Comment: @jimmy_keen Well, durrr... don't I feel like a fool.  You are of course completely correct, the answer was stating me in the face all the time.  Thank you.